# VirtualBox: Why Virtual Hard Disk is showing more space than assigned?

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, virtualbox

I am using VirtualBox Version 4.3.20. Host operating system is Windows 7 Professional Service Pack 1, 64-bit.

I created a Virtual Machine for Linux Ubuntu 13.10. For the Virtual Hard Drive I set the size as 16 GB. In the Windows Explorer I can see that the size of VDI file is 16 GB. While installing Linux Ubuntu, I selected the option for creating manual partition. There I saw that the Virtual Hard Drive size is showing as 17.2 GB. This is what is being shown:

> /dev/sda ATA VBOX HARDDISK (17.2 GB)

How come Linux is thinking that the virtual hard disk is 1.2 GB bigger than actual size?

Comment: It's the difference between GiB and GB. 17.2GiB = 16GB. Everything is fine except, of course, the use of an outdated and unsupported Ubuntu release. Whichever reason you might think you have for that, forget it, you're wrong, and pretty please do NOT allow internet access to the VM unless you're using a supported release. Be socially responsible, thank you.

Comment: Good question.  +1.  And feel free to use what ever version of Ubuntu you want!

Comment: @MichaelBay if it is `GiB` then why Ubuntu is showing it as `GB` on screen?